# Can't read an XML file with R

Tags: r, xml

I'm new to the xml format, and this file ("https://data.stortinget.no/eksport/sak?sakid=76122") is giving me trouble.

these are the packages that several google searches suggested me:

- "XML" xmlToDataFrame and xmlparse give me the Error: "XML content does not seem to be XML: ''"
- "xml2" i can't understand how to bring the output of read_xml to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know why it cannot be read directly by the `XML` package, the following scripts works fine

```
XML::xmlParse(httr::content(httr::GET("https://data.stortinget.no/eksport/sak?sakid=76122")))
```